# Opposite of 'is' in if statement?

Tags: if-statement, swift

I want to see if this statement is false:

```
if twData is Array {
}
```

`isnt` and `isnot` don't seem to exist.

This doesn't work:

```
if (twData is Array) == false {
}
```

So I'm not sure exactly how to do this, other than the less clean:

```
if twData is Array {
} else {
//Code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know the generic type stored in the array, then you should make it explicit:

```
if !(twData is Array<Int>) {
    // Do something
}
```

If instead you just want to know if it's an array regardless of the generic type, then you have to use `NSArray`:

```
if !(twData is NSArray) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

```
let isarray = twData is Array
if !isarray  {
    do something
}
```

Comment: That produces an error in a playground: `Cannot invoke '!' with an argument of type 'Bool'` - I know, it doesn't make sense